# JQuery manipulation of a SELECT element

Tags: jquery

I am doing some manipulation of the options contained in a Select element. Is there a way to

- remove all elements
- Search an element in the list of already present options
- update an option attribute (e.g. set as selected)

I am using jQuery 1.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look through the API at the [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/), [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/), and [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) methods.

First

```
$('#mySelect').html('')
```

Second

```
$('#mySelect option').each( function() {
     if ($(this).val() == 'valueToChoose') {
        ...
     }
});
```

Third

```
$('#mySelect').val('valueToChoose');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the select statment has id="my_select".

Remove all options:

```
 $('#my_select').empty()
```

Find an element:

```
$('#my_select > option[value=' + value_to_find + '])
```

Set option as selected (assuming you know the value):

```
$('#my_select').val(the_value);
```